# How do I iterate through a list of tuples?

Tags: python, while-loop, tuples, iteration

I am having some doubts with this homework on python. The exercise consists on the following:

> This bus has a passenger entry and exit control system to monitor the number of occupants it carries and thus detect when there is too high a capacity.
>
> At each stop the entry and exit of passengers is represented by a tuple consisting of two integer numbers.
>
> ```
> bus_stop = (in, out)
> ```
>
> The succession of stops is represented by a list of these tuples.
>
> ```
> stops = [(in1, out1), (in2, out2), (in3, out3), (in4, out4)]
> ```
>
> Goals:
>
> - Use lists, tuples
> - Use while/for loops
> - Use minimum, maximum, length
> - Use average, standard deviation
>
> Tasks:
>
> - Calculate the number of stops.
> - Assign to a variable a list whose elements are the number of passengers at each stop (in-out),
> - Find the maximum occupation of the bus.

So far I've come up with this code but it's not returning anything, so, definitely I am doing something wrong due to my inexperience with python.

```
bus_is_full = False
bus_capacity = 0
stops = [(20, 0), (13, 7), (40, 10), (1, 20)]
while not bus_is_full == True:
    for stop in stops:
        bus_capacity = stops()
        if bus_capacity == 50:
            bus_is_full = True
            stops +=1 
        elif bus_capacity < 50:
            stops +=1
    print(bus_capacity)
```

Comment: for a debugging question, I see you provided the input, and your current output (nothing) so good start. You also must say what the output "should be".

Comment: bus_capacity = stops()?

Comment: When I try to run the code as posted, I get an error. That counts as output, so you should have posted that as well.

Comment: You should only ask one question at a time on stackoverflow. Read your "Goals" again and think of a better way to determine the number of stops, using a single call to a python builtin function that you're supposed to be using. (although it is misspelled in the "Goals" section)

Comment: Beside the point, but `while not bus_is_full == True` -> `while not bus_is_full`

Comment: Nothing in the problem says anything about the bus being full or only being able to carry 50 people. Where did that come from? It clearly goes over 50.

Comment: This will help on part two: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences towards the lower part of that small section.

Answer (score 0):

Code below stops at 3rd stop with capacity exceeded 50 (actual population 56)

```
bus_is_full = False
bus_capacity = 0
stops = [(20, 0), (13, 7), (40, 10), (1, 20)]
stops_count = 0 # count the number of bust stops till capacity limit reached (including this stop)
for stop in stops:
    bus_capacity += stop[0] - stop[1]  # update tot bus_capacity with change in current bus stop (e.g if (13, 7) -> +6 people added)
    if bus_capacity >= 50:
        bus_is_full = True
        stops_count += 1 
        break
    elif bus_capacity < 50:
        stops_count += 1
print(bus_capacity)
print(stops_count)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cast your tuple into a list.

```py
    bus_is_full = False
    bus_capacity = 0
    stops = [(20, 0), (13, 7), (40, 10), (1, 20)]
    number_stops = len(stops)
    print("The number of stops is : {0}\n".format(bus_capacity))
    i=0
    while i < number_stops :
        for stop in stops:
            l = list(stop)
            in_i = l[0]
            out_i = l[1]
            print("For the {0} stop, {1} passengers entered and {2} passengers left the bus".format(i, in_i, out_i) )
            i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly simpler way to write what Sultan1991 said

```
bus_capacity = 0
stops = [(20, 0), (13, 7), (40, 10), (1, 20)]
num_stops = 0
for on, off in stops:
    bus_capacity += on - off
    num_stops += 1
    if bus_capacity >= 50:
       break
print("Bus capacity:", bus_capacity)
print("Number of stops:",num_stops)
```

Also a heads up: Looping like this is not particularly performant on large data sets. So if you are working with more data than just this I would suggest looking at the `numpy` or `pandas` libraries as they could significantly speed up and reduce the necessary memory for operations like this.